# How to call subquery for each document in the processor of spring batch

Tags: spring, spring-batch

In reader of spring batch, there is one query which fetch id and other details from the database. And inside processor, these details are set into objects. (like, id, department, name)

But I have to query for each document again for some other information.(like, to find the subjects of that department) and then again set this information to model object.

So, how to call this second query. In another step or inside processor?

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no another step inside the processor. You can for example inject a `JdbcTemplate` in your item processor and do the additional query.